# Dart: indexed_db open version

Tags: dart

I need to use indexedDb for local storage.

When opening an indexedDb, the version is passed, and I presume that indicates whether an upgrade is needed. Can someone please explain what happens here and in particular the significance of the version, where the version is obtained from and also what an upgrade is?

For example :

```dart
import 'dart:indexed_db' as idb;

final int _iDbVersion = 1;

void fOpenDb(String sDbName) {
  var request = window.indexedDB.open(sDbName, _iDbVersion);
  request.on.success.add((e) => fDbOnOpened(request.result));
  request.on.error.add(fDbOnOpenError);
  request.on.upgradeNeeded.add((e) => fDbOnUpgradeNeeded(request.transaction));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this interesting description which appears to me to be largely correct. :

IndexedDb:
DATABASE

For every origin you can create an infinite number of databases. The only thing you need to create a database is an unique name. A database also has a version, this version will be used to determine the structure of the database. When a database is created for the first time, the version will be an empty string. Each database can only have one version at a time, this means the database can’t exist in multiple versions at once.

VERSION

The set of object stores can be changed, but it can only change by using the Version_change transaction. This transaction will change the version of the database and change the set of object stores as you defined.